# Multiple accounts in XMPPFramework

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I am new in XMPPFramework and I try to investigate it. So I have a question. Can XMPPFramework support multiple account login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use multiple instances of XMPPStream, one for each account.

Comment: @Mehul – yes, this is an answer to the question.